# Is it possible to set a rule on a People Picker control in InfoPath

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have an InfoPath form below:

[image]

Below is what I'm trying to accomplish:

- If Status = Assign New Designee then Assign Alternate Designee (People Picker Control) cannot be blank and requires to be filled in with data.

I have tried and cannot seem to find a way around it.

How can I accomplish the above condition?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run a **validation rule** on a **people picker** field, however this is what you can do to achieve the same effect:

1. You can **create** a single line **text field**.
2. Set the **default value** of the **text box** to be populated by the **people picker** field (**Display Name**, Username (AccountID), or Account Type).
3. Place the text field into your form
4. Put a **formatting rule** that **hide**s this field.
5. Put a **validation rule** on that **text box**.
6. if **Status** changes run **validation rule** on hidden **text box**, so user can see only people picker but error message from textbox.

You will need to change some cosmetics according to your requirement.

This is the only way you can run dynamic rules on people picker.

Comment: Thanks,

You actually beat me to the punch in answering:) I was able to implement what you suggested and it works great.

I have only one problem with it. I found out that if I decide to only enter a New Designee without setting the Status to "Assign New Designee" that it lets me click Continue.

I was expecting there to be a validation error but nothing happened. How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Create a validation rule on textbox like if "status" field "is equal to" "Assign New Designee" type your error message on "Screen tip". on your form submit also take care of your validations. please refer below articale to create conditional require fields in infopath https://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot put a Validation rule on a people picker field, but you can end up creating a calculated helper field and place the validation on the helper field.